# JQuery ajax request - global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So, I have this code:

```
$.post("contacts.php", 
    {zip: $("#zip").val()}, "json").done(function(data){
        var response = JSON.parse(data);
        $("#city").val(response[0].city);
        });}
```

It posts the zip code to the server, and the server returns the city name corresponding to the zip. Now the problem is, I want to access response[0].city outside of the done function. The problem is, I can't declare it as global. I tried to lose the var, I read that it declares it as global, but nop. Also tried to declare it as the first thing in my script, outside of any functions, still nop. It can't be accessed. I also tried to define a completly different variable as global, pass it the response variable to save it. Still nop.

Comment: You cannot. Period.

Comment: Could u assign it to a hidden input on the page?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `$.ajax` instead of `$.post` so I can make it synchronous with `async: false`, then just create the variable before the `$.ajax` like this:

```
var city;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "contacts.php",
    data: { zip: $("#zip").val() },
    success: function(data) {
        var response = JSON.parse(data);
        city = response[0].city;
    },
    // by setting async: false the code after the 
    // $.ajax will not execute until it has completed
    async: false
});

// some operation with the city variable
```

---

**NOTE:** as of recently the usage of `async: false` is deprecated with jQuery and modern browsers. You should find a solution that does not involve using `async: false`.

Comment: Nope, tried it. city is undefined. And I know the done function is ran, cause I even tested it with an Alert("IT WORKS");

Comment: Okay, It works. You are right. The rest of the code is "calculated", without taking the ajax response into account. This way it waits for it. Thanks ^^

Comment: Can you call a function and pass the response through to it from `.done`? I would not recommend `async:false` some browsers throw up a warning message in the console because it degrades performance so much. Also "As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated" http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: According to the message you can still use the `success` callback with `async: false`. "you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done()"